# How to align every column of an Eigen matrix?

Tags: eigen, simd, memory-alignment

If the number of rows in an Eigen matrix is not a multiple of the alignment step (usually 16 bytes), then it seems only the first column of the matrix will be aligned. For example:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf m(7, 7);
std::cout << "1st column start address: " << &m(0, 0) << "\n";
std::cout << "2nd column start address: " << &m(0, 1) << "\n";
```

```
1st column start address: 0x100704c80
2nd column start address: 0x100704c9c
```

The first column is aligned, the second is not.

I am writing external SIMD code that accesses this matrix. It can be fastest if we can guarantee that each column starts at an aligned address. What is the idiomatic way to have Eigen allocate my matrix such that every column is aligned?

Comment: Make matrix 8x8 instead of 7x7 and use its data in 7x7 outside of your algorithm?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I assume that would defeat much of the benefit of Eigen, unless it lets you take slice views of larger matrices (so storage geometry differs from actual geometry).  Otherwise you couldn't use Eigen's matmul and so on functions that need dimensions to match another 7x7 matrix.  Also, you'd only need an 8x7 not 8x8 matrix to pad reach row (or pad each column?) to a multiple of 8 elements, as long as you pick the right dimension to pad.

Comment: As @huseyintugrulbuyukisik says, but a 8x7 matrix would be sufficient (for column-major matrices). And you can access the relevant part using `m.topRows(7)` if you want to use it in Eigen expressions. Also, note that on modern CPUs memory alignment is not as important as it used to be (it still has benefits, whether they are big enough to justify the memory and convenience overhead depends)

Comment: @PeterCordes what if whole matrix data fits into avx registers? Maybe extracting from simd register is faster than manually aligning memory? I mean, 7x7 can be read into registers in just 7-8 operations then shifted?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: It totally depends what you're doing with the data, whether it's useful to have each column (or each row) in a separate pair of registers, with the elements lining up with each other, vs. packing head to tail without regard for column boundaries.  The latter is useful for element-wise operations like matrix addition; that's just like flat array addition.  Other operations, not so much.  Presumably the OP is doing something that Eigen doesn't already have functions for, but yeah worth reminding them of the possibility.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: But *extracting* an aligned column from packed AVX registers?  No, that wouldn't be faster than an unaligned vector load.  Especially without AVX-512 `valignd`, it's a big pain to shuffle together a pair of 256-bit vectors to extract a contiguous window.  Like `vpalignr` and then a lane-crossing shuffle to fix up the result?  And calculating or looking up shuffle masks for a given integer offset is extra work if it's not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Only zen 4 architecture has support for fast lane-crossing full 512bit shuffles right? @PeterCordes

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: No, Intel CPUs handle 512-bit shuffles pretty much the same as 256-bit shuffles: 1/clock throughput with 3-cycle latency for lane-crossing shuffles.  (Some 256-bit shuffles have better throughput on Ice Lake and later, able to run on the second shuffle unit on port 1, but IDK if any of those are lane-crossing.  In-lane shuffles also have only 1c latency.)  It's notable for Zen 4 which mostly has only 256-bit wide vector ALUs, so we might expect more uops for 512-bit lane-xing shuffles. Zen 4 has higher latency and worse tput for wider shuffles, but still single uop.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'm aware I can use a different size and `topRows()`. Also aware of `conservativeResize()` which might be part of my solution, if only as, a user, I knew which of the many Eigen macros to use as the alignment multiple.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm gong with for now. It's not ideal because the user of the matrix must always use `topRows()` or equivalent technique for `.rows()` to return desired number of active rows.

```
// rounds up the number of rows/cols to ensure each col/row starts aligned
template <class M>
inline void resizeAligned(M &m, Eigen::Index rows, Eigen::Index cols)
{
    static constexpr auto mask = EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES - 1;
    
    auto &size = m.IsRowMajor ? cols : rows;
    size = (size + mask) & ~mask;

    m.resize(rows, cols);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that copy around data from an existing matrix object after you create it with the "wrong" storage geometry?  So that's not ideal either.  But could be ok for matrices that you keep around across many uses per time you create them, especially for smallish dimensions like 7x7.

Comment: Sorry, should have said, I create it empty, @PeterCordes